# How to ensure the scheduled executor runs even after a runtime Exception

Tags: java, executorservice

I have a very long running task that periodically polls a web service for XML content. I am using a Scheduled executor for these periodic runs and everything works fine.

The JavaDoc of [ScheduledExecutorService scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) state that

> - ... If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed ...*

This clearly implies that in case of unhandled exceptions, The application even though running , is effectively in a stopped state and doing nothing.

I want to ensure that the task execution does not stop, Apart from catching all exceptions, is there any other way to deal with this?

```
@Override 
public void run() {
  try {
       // fetch xml feed from network, 
       // parse the feed and dump to file the json.
  } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Unhandled exception " + e);}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is another way around other than catching all Exceptions in the run method.
If you don't mind using 3rd party libraries, you could use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). Take a look at [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example6).

*hth*

Comment: Accepting you answer as I was not aware of the quartz, it gives me another option, Thanks